# Count repeated value in list of tuple

Tags: python, tuples

Given my list

```py
myListOf=[("a", "b"), ("a", "c"), ("a", "d")]
```

I want to know how many time `a` is repeated in list

I tried with a empty list, iterate `myListOf` and append, and use `collection.Counter` to return the values. Is the best way to do it?

```py
counter_one = []
myListOf = [("a", "b"), ("a", "c"), ("a", "d")]
for i in myListOf:
    for e in i:
        counter_one.append(e)
print(Counter(counter_one))
```

```
>>> Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 1})
```

This for my use case is kinda... "weird", because this can be huge...

This is use case:
I have to connect to a DB and write the data into CSV, I have all of this done and working, but now I have to know the most repeated value from a `column`

```sql
SELECT col_one, col_two, col_three FROM table_name
```

This return a list of tuple and I have to say `The most repeated in col_one is SOME_VALUE`, if I use my current method, I can't access to a specific column (I append all values).

Comment: FWIW: [`from itertools import chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) `Counter(chain.from_iterable(myListOf))`…

Comment: Having flattened the list, you can count the results directly.